# I want to call my API in directive and use the directive where I need. Could anyone help me. Please fine my example

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display API data by calling API in the directive, Could any one help me.
app.component.html

```html
<label>Display Titles</label>
<select class="rounded-inputs20
select-select col-md-3">
  <option appDropdown></option>
</select>
```

dropdown.directive.ts

```js
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Directive
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  displaytitle: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  gettitle() {
    this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.displaytitle = data;
        console.log('titles', data);
      });
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-bfrzcs?file=dropdown.directive.ts

Comment: please also include code sample in post

Comment: I have provide the stackablitz ,please find it

Comment: Note there must still be a [mre] _in the question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't like using an HTTP request inside a directive, but here you are the solution.

#### *Directive*

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  displaytitle: any;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private el: ElementRef
    ) {
    el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.gettitle();
  }

  gettitle() {
    this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .subscribe(data => {
          Object.values(data).forEach((e) => this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML += `<option>${e.title}</otpion>`);
      });
  }
}
```

You have to "take" your current element to be able to handle it and write your data. So use `ElementRef`.

#### *Component template*

```html
<select class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3" appDropdown>
</select>
```

In order to write every option, you have to use the `directive` in `select`